# Has EL&U stopped tweeting?

Tags: discussion, twitter

Does anyone know why no question has been tweeted since 8 Feb 2023?

The last tweet was ***[How does one pronounce Pompey?](https://mobile.twitter.com/StackEnglish)***, and then nothing has happened for more than a week.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No questions have been (automatically) tweeted since February 8th, 2023 on *any* Stack Exchange site. No questions will be (automatically) tweeted after that either.

You are one of the few people who were paying attention to Stack Exchange's tweets. Twitter changed its rules for bots and SE decided it wasn't worthwhile to maintain the integration.

See [Are the various site Tweetbots affected by the upcoming Twitter API changes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386451/323179)

(Note: the Hot Network Question list is completely unaffected — we've had several recent ones such as [Confusion from a Vocative Comma before a List](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603252/191178) .)

Comment: Mm, sad. I liked to see them tweeted. it seemed to me it boosted interest in good questions and even added new users. But it may be just my own impression. Thanks, that pretty much answers my question.

Comment: It was news to me that they were tweeted. If I'd known, I'm not sure I'd've approved. But I'm glad it's not being done any more. We really don't need to encourage questions from people who get their grammar understanding from twitter.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was seeing it the other way round... The EL&U standards could have helped improve the knowledge of English for those interested, but in little "pills" instead of whole grammar treatises that nobody reads.

Comment: @fev I see the EL&U standards somewhat differently than you do, apparently.

Comment: @JohnLawler The tweets were more for people already active here to become aware of "hot" questions. From the Meta post on the API: *While I can't easily tell you how many people are coming to the sites through those links, I'm guessing it's next to none, and that even the people who might be… they'd likely be visiting the site anyway.*

Comment: Yes we don't need to backwardly endorse unhealthy,  socially damaging political entities like Witter.